# Model.matrix contrast error

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a dynamic string to create a `model.matrix`. Value of string is as follows:

```
total_matrix_str
[1] "model.matrix( ~ date + MDSE_ITEM_I + COLR_N + SLS_TYPE_GRP_C + dayofwk +
 MDSE_ITEM_REF_I + WK_END_D + GREG_D + SIZE_N + MDSE_STYL_N + COLR_FMLY_N + LATTD_I 
+ LNGTD_I + weekend + dsp + assort_size + colr_per + pctTillDate + weeknr + MEANTEMPM 
+ MEANVISM + MEANWINDSPDM + MAXHUMIDITY + MINHUMIDITY + MEANDEWPTM + MEANPRESSUREM 
+ FOG + RAIN + THUNDER ,data =  total ,
contrasts.arg =list( MDSE_ITEM_I=contrasts(total$MDSE_ITEM_I,contrasts = F) , 
CO_LOC_I=contrasts(total$CO_LOC_I,contrasts = F) ,
COLR_N=contrasts(total$COLR_N,contrasts = F) ,
dayofwk=contrasts(total$dayofwk,contrasts = F) ,
SIZE_N=contrasts(total$SIZE_N,contrasts = F) ,
MDSE_STYL_N=contrasts(total$MDSE_STYL_N,contrasts = F) ,
COLR_FMLY_N=contrasts(total$COLR_FMLY_N,contrasts = F) ,
assort_size=contrasts(total$assort_size,contrasts = F) ,
weeknr=contrasts(total$weeknr,contrasts = F) ))"
```

Here are distinct value counts of the categorical variables:

```
> length(unique(total$MDSE_ITEM_I))
[1] 30
> length(unique(total$CO_LOC_I))
[1] 5
> length(unique(total$COLR_N))
[1] 6
> length(unique(total$dayofwk))
[1] 7
> length(unique(total$SIZE_N))
[1] 9
> length(unique(total$MDSE_STYL_N))
[1] 6
> length(unique(total$COLR_FMLY_N))
[1] 4
> length(unique(total$assort_size))
[1] 7
> length(unique(total$weeknr))
[1] 7
```

still this command results in error as follows:

```
total_matrix <- eval(parse(text = total_matrix_str))
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Any clues why I might be getting this error? How to resolve error dynamically by auto detecting such scenario?

Comment: check for `NA` values in your data ...

Comment: Also probably check to make sure one of the variables that you _think_ isn't a factor is actually a factor (there are lots of variables in that formula that haven't seemed to check).

Comment: @joran Checked missing categorical from contrasts have just one or two levels so should not go. However one aberration is variable `SLS_TYPE_GRP_C` which have unique STRING value. Can it cause trouble?

Comment: @abhiieor I apologize, I'm having difficulty understanding what you said in that last comment. If `SLS_TYPE_GRP_C` is not integer or numeric, and there is only one unique value, then yes, it could cause problems.

Comment: Indeed thats the problem..Ran w/o `SLS_TYPE_GRP_C` and it worked. Any idea why this creates problem even though there is no contrast corresponding this column?

Comment: All non-integer/numeric variables will have contrasts, either the default contrasts or the ones you specify. Your `contrasts.arg` overrides the default contrasts for certain variables you specify - any other categorical variables will get default contrasts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is coming because of single unique value of one string variable.

In Gregor's words:

> All non-integer/numeric variables will have contrasts, either the
> default contrasts or the ones you specify. Your contrasts.arg
> overrides the default contrasts for certain variables you specify -
> any other categorical variables will get default contrasts.

So essentially all factor and string variables will inevitably get contrasts. However this will fail if any factor or string variable have just one unique value.